# Converting a string formatted in hex in Python to binary data correctly

Tags: python, string, binary

I have a string formatted as '\x00\x00\x00\x00' and need it to be formatted such that, when printed, it appears in the console as b'\x00\x00\x00\x00'

How do I do this?

edit: I had a different version of the code printing out a string formatted with b'\xf4\x00\x00\x00' etc and on my computer it prints '\xf4\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: Do you just want `"\x00\x00\x00\x00".encode()`?

Comment: Do you mean you need it to print out with double quotes instead of single? Because if you just simply do z = b"\x00\x00\x00\x00" and then print that, it would come out with single quotes but it would otherwise look as you are requesting.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Just tried it and it gives me a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128). I've been able to print the string on another computer successfully, but unfortunately I don't have access to it for a bit so I can't just look at how it's formatted differently

Comment: I tested what Mark wrote on several repls and it worked fine for me. Not imports or anything else needed. I think perhaps you have an issue that is not directly related to your question. Is the data you posted the data you had the error with?

Comment: @mikarm no, I mean that I had a different version of the code printing out a string formatted with b'\xf4\x00\x00\x00' etc and on my computer it prints '\xf4\x00\x00\x00'

Comment: @Matthew you can try adding the encoding like `utf-8`: `s.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @mikarm I just tried encoding '\xf4' and it gives me the UnicodeDecodeError. But I am fairly positive I saw the other computer I was working on use the same data but was formatted with a b'\xf4\x00\x00\x00........etc'

Comment: @Matthew are you still using Python 2?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Oh wow, that was the issue in the difference. I ran it with python3 and now it's formatted correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @MarkMeyer That also solved all my other code issues I've been having the past few days...d'oh! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just add the b literal before the string, in that way you'll be defining the string as bytes

```
# example
s = b"\x00\x00\x00\x00" 
print(s)
```

If instead you're receiving the string from somewhere else and you're not manually writing it you can just encode the string into bytes

```
# an other example
# let's pretend that we received the value from, say, a function
s = "\x00\x00\x00\x00".encode() # again, pretend that this value has just been retrieved from a function
print(s)
```